# Apache url not Accessible

Tags: apache, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I have to check the access of a apache server.I have written  a standalone code for cheking the access of a apache server. If i simply type the url it is accessable...But wen i run it through code it throws exception..

as java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://10.98.12.151:80/server-status?auto

What is 403 response code ??
hw can i make it accessible from standalone code...

This is my code
connecturl = "http://" + ip + ":" + port + "/server-status?auto";
targetURL = new URL(connecturl);
     HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetURL.openConnection();

```
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        httpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");


        httpURLConnection.connect();
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403
are you missing the extension of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The 403 code is an "access denied" code.  Other codes definitions can be found at [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

The cause is likely due to  directive in your httpd.conf file not having an "Allow from" that includes the ip of the host you're trying to run the program on.

For example, you're trying running this from a client (10.98.12.10) and want to check the status of the webserver you have running on 10.98.12.151.

Make sure the httpd.conf file on the server has something like the following:

```
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
# now make sure your client host is allowed to connect to this location
  Allow from 10.98.12.10
</Location>
```

Good luck.